# Terminal command to list application defaults?

Tags: applications, command-line, macos, defaults

I'm new to Mac from the Linux world, and I am looking for a command or file providing a list to default user applications associated with certain filetypes.  For example, on Linux:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

provides the application names and priority hierarchies on Linux.  I've tried something similar using `defaults` on the Mac, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

```
$ defaults read | grep pdf
  name = "1309.0238.pdf";
  name = "1309.0238.pdf";
```

Does the Mac operating system have a simple, command-line function or accessible file to find the default applications?

Answer (score 4):

There is a third-party github project called [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps), which provides a **command line tool** and a MacOS Preference pane for listing and setting the URIs, UTIs and their app handlers.

```
Utility to retrieve and manipulate default applications in macOS.

Available commands: 
- getHandler                              Returns the default application registered for the URI Scheme or <subtype> you specify.
- getApps                                 Returns a list of all registered applications.
- getSchemes                              Returns a list of all known URI schemes, accompanied by their default handler.
- getUTIs                                 Returns a list of all known UTIs, and their default handler.
- setHandler                              Sets <application> as the default handler for a given <type>/<subtype> combination.
- help                                    Prints this help information
- version                                 Prints the current version of this app
```

.
(It's a replacement for the long-standing [RCDefaultsApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) pane, which completely stopped working in Catalina.)

Comment: Works with the CLI (but not the GUI strangely). `swda setHandler --app /Applications/VLC.app --UTI public.mp3` . Finally I can get rid of that obnoxious Apple music for my mp3 files when listening to music at work.

Answer (score 2):

Not easily. You can use the well-hidden `lsregister` command to dump the contents of the Launch Services database, which is what controls which file types open with which applications:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump
```

but its output isn't well documented -- there's [some info here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2004100508111340), but it's over 10 years old so it's probably at least partially obsolete. A bit of Googling turns up some AppleScripts for further parsing, that you might be able to adopt:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3452435/476909
- https://macosx.com/threads/howto-list-your-installed-applications.26204/

Comment: You can also use:  `/S*/L*/F*/C*/F*/L*/S*/lsregister -dump`